# q-toggle with q-table in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a table with the quasar framework and vue.js, and I'm implementing a switch toggle to change if the current data row is enabled or disabled, even though I'm developing based on model driven design and toggle button is switching to the entirely table at the UI, and I only need the selected one. I know that the issue is because of the variable I'm passing to the v-model, but I can´t figure it out.

[this is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7kmi.png)

here is my generic class called generic data, due to support many other tables along the software.

```
<template>
  <q-page class="q-pa-md items-start">
    <q-card class="col-12 row q-pa-sm no-shadow action-bar">
      <q-input class="col-4" dense v-model="search" :label="`Pesquisar ${globalData.mainTitle}`" clearable />
      <q-select class="col-3" dense style="margin-left: 20px;" v-model="selectedGroup" :options="groups" label="Grupos"
        v-if="isChartOfAccounts" @update:model-value="tableFilter()" />
      <q-space />
      <q-space />
      <q-btn unelevated square align="left" no-caps color="secondary" :label="$t('reload')" icon="fal fa-sync"
        @click="startData()" class="q-mr-sm" />
      <q-btn unelevated square align="left" no-caps color="primary" :label="$t('new')" icon="fal fa-plus"
        @click="register()" />
    </q-card>
    <div class="q-mt-xl">
      <paymentBox v-if="$route.meta.route === 'AuthorizedPayments'" />
    </div>
    <div class="row q-mt-md">

   
   <q-table :rows-per-page-options="[0]" virtual-scroll class="no-shadow col-12" :filter="search"
        :pagination="initialPagination" :loading="loading" :rows="registers" :columns="columns" row-key="id">
        <template v-slot:loading>
          <q-inner-loading showing color="primary" />
        </template>
        <template v-slot:body-cell-tags="props">
          <q-td :props="props">
            <q-chip color="primary" text-color="white" size="sm" v-for="(tag, idx) in mapTags(props.row.tags)"
              :key="idx">{{ tag.name }}</q-chip> </q-td>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:body-cell-actions="props">
          <q-td :props="props">
            <div class="actions">
              <q-btn round unelevated size="sm" icon="fal fa-edit" color="primary" @click="register(props.row.id)" />
              <span v-if="isChartOfAccounts">
                <template>
                  <q-toggle class="q-pl-xs" v-model="categoryStatus" color="green" checked-icon="check" size="xs"
                    @click="changeCategoryStatus(props.row.id)" :class="{ 'custom-disabled-style': !categoryStatus }" />
                  <q-tooltip>
                    Status da categoria
                  </q-tooltip>
                </template>
              </span>
            </div>
          </q-td>
        </template>
        <!-- <template v-if="$route.meta.route == 'payables'" v-slot:body-cell-advance="props">
          <q-td :props="props">
            <div class="actions">
              <q-btn v-if="$route.meta.route == 'payables'" round unelevated size="sm" icon="fal fa-arrow-right"
                color="primary" @click="register(props.row.id)" />
            </div>
          </q-td>
        </template> -->
      </q-table>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

and the script that I'm working on

```
   
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { listColumns } from 'src/definitions/';
import { updateCategoryStatus } from 'src/pages/mutations/updateCategoryStatus'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'listData',
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      loading: false,
      registers: [],
      groups: [],
      selectedGroup: [],
      isChartOfAccounts: false,
      categoryStatus: null,

      aux: [],
      initialPagination: {
        rowsPerPage: 0,
      },
      tags: null,
      columns: listColumns[this.$route.name],
    };
  },
  components: {},
  activated() {
    console.log('activated');
  },
  mounted() {
    window.CURRENT = this;
    this.globalData.mainTitle = this.$route.meta.title;
    console.log('mounted', this.$route.meta)
    this.startData();
  },
  watch: {
    $route() {
      this.startData(
        this.$route.meta?.reFetchPolicy || 'network-only'
      );
    },
  },
  methods: {
    startData(cacheType = undefined) {
      const meta = this.$route.meta
      const document = meta?.gqlSchema

      this.$route.meta.route === 'chartofaccounts' ? this.isChartOfAccounts = true : this.isChartOfAccounts = false
      if (meta && document) {
        const temp = Object.entries(meta.gqlSchema)
        const [schemaName, schema] = temp[0]

        const cache = cacheType || this.$route.meta?.fetchPolicy || 'cache-first';

        if (this.$route.meta.route === 'AuthorizedPayments' || this.$route.meta.route === 'waitingapproval') {
          if (this.$route.meta.route === 'AuthorizedPayments') {
            var status = 'approved'
          } else if (this.$route.meta.route === 'waitingapproval') {
            var status = 'waiting_approval'
          }
          this.$apollo.query({
            query: schema,
            variables: {
              status: status,
            },
          }).then(res => {
            let data = res.data['payablesByStatus'];
            if (data) {
              if (meta.handleResponse) {
                data = meta.handleResponse(data)
              }
              this.registers = data;
            } else {
              console.log('TODO: Tratar erro aqui')
            }
          })
        } else {
          this.$apollo.query({
            query: schema,
            fetchPolicy: cache,
          }).then(res => {
            let data = res.data[schemaName]

            data.forEach((sort) => {
              if (!this.groups.includes(sort.name)) { this.groups.push(sort.name) }
              this.aux.push(sort)
              sort.categories.forEach((s) => {
                s.status == 'enabled' ? this.categoryStatus = true : this.categoryStatus = false
                console.log(this.categoryStatus)

              })
            })

            if (data) {

              if (meta.handleResponse) {
                data = meta.handleResponse(data)
              }
              this.registers = data;
            } else {
              console.log('TODO: Tratar erro aqui')
            }
          })
        }
      }
    },



    tableFilter() {
      this.aux.filter((x) => x.name == this.selectedGroup).forEach((catGroup) => {
        this.registers = catGroup.categories
      })
      return this.registers
    },

    changeCategoryStatus(id) {
      this.$apollo.mutate({
        mutation: updateCategoryStatus,
        variables: {
          newStatus: this.categoryStatus == true ? 'enabled' : 'disabled',
          categoryId: id
        }
      }).then(() => {
        this.successfullyConcluded();
      })
    },

    mapTags(val) {
      if (!this.tags) return '';
      if (!val) return '';
      if (Object.entries(val).length === 0) return '';
      let ret = [];

      val.forEach((element) => {
        ret.push(this.tags.find((x) => x.id === element));
      });

      return ret;
    },

  },
  setup() {
    return {};
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped>
.title {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.approved {
  width: 200px;
}

.custom-disabled-style {
  color: red;
  /* Adjust styling as needed */
}
</style>
```

I really would appreciate if someone provide some help

I tried to iterate when listing the data to the table inside the forEach loop
here

```
   data.forEach((sort) => {
              if (!this.groups.includes(sort.name)) { this.groups.push(sort.name) }
              this.aux.push(sort)
              sort.categories.forEach((s) => {
                s.status == 'enabled' ? this.categoryStatus = true : this.categoryStatus = false
                console.log(this.categoryStatus)

              })
            })
```

I also was thinking of something like making a loop only for the q-toggle and filtering for the row.id, even though I think it might not be a good practice to do it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkPoe.png)

Comment: they're all bound to the exact same v-model, that's why toggling one toggles them all. 
 given 20 rows, you'd need 20 different v-models, or an array with 20 indices with the v-models each bound to different index.  it's not clear what your row data looks like, but if you had some type of `categoryStatus` property for each row object, you could bind the v-model to each row object's `categoryStatus` property.  in the quasar table it'd end up looking something like `v-model="props.row.categoryStatus"`.  but you have to create this property on each object first.